# php virtual (''); works but php include''; does not

Tags: php, server-side-includes, php-include

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following. All of the reading I've done says that 'include' should work. I'm wondering 'why' I have to use the 'virtual()' and/or WHAT I'm doing wrong with the 'include'.

```
<?php virtual('/path'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php include'/path'; ?>
```

I use both in the code below. The 'virtual()' works and is used for header.php. The 'include' (does not work) and is used for footer.php. The code for the entire page is below.
[Link to live page](http://ghsglobaltech.guhsd.net/student_sites/2013/web_40/pages/css_includes/index.php)

```
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="/student_sites/2013/web_40/pages/css_includes/css_includes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"><?php virtual('/student_sites/2013/web_40/pages/css_includes/assets/includes/header.php'); ?>
</div>
  <div id="content_wrapper">Content for New CONTENT WRAPPER Div Tag Goes Here
<div id="side_bar">Content for New SIDE BAR Div Tag Goes Here</div>
    <div id="content">Content for New CONTENT Div Tag Goes Here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"><?php include '/student_sites/2013/web_40/pages/css_includes/assets/includes/footer.php'; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for both of those functions?

Comment: I had no idea `virtual()` even existed, so I Googled it and now I know what it does. Why couldn't you do the same?

Comment: @Marty, yes, but I'm still VERY new to PHP and <CODE>. I didn't notice anything I was doing wrong. I did notice that that the "virtual()" is specific for Apache servers. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks you!

Comment: @Bojangles, I could, but I'm a high school teacher and I want to be able to explain the difference to my students and "why" one is working and the other isn't. Thanks again!

Comment: What error do you get when you use <?php include('/student_sites/2013/web_40/pages/css_includes/assets/includes/header.php'); ?> instead of the virtual function? Virtual seems to be only useful for including CGI scripts or .shtml files. I think include should work fine.

Comment: @weiver, I do not get an error. The included file simply does not appear.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the file. Make sure you upload the file in ASCII and not binary. If you use Notepad++, open the file and in Format menu chose encode in utf-8 without BOM and save it. Then reupload file, and the include should work.

Comment: These 2 verbs are SO NOT SIMILIAR and DO NOT do similiar thing at all. I would suggest that you ignore the `virtual()` command completely, like 99% of all PHP developers have before you.

Comment: @weiver, If I use virtual('') for 'footer.php', it displays in the page as it should. But, if I use include'', it does not display and I do not receive an error. 
Does this something with my server? Is the <CODE> entered correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include'/path'; ?>
```

Doesn't work because of the type of file it's in. This statement must use the 'virtual()' which only works in php files. The 'include' only works in html or shtml files.

```
<!--#include virtual="/path" -->
```

for html files and

```
<?php virtual('/path'); ?>
```

for php files.

The html code still uses *virtual* but *include* as well, so I'm still not sure why it can't use *include* by itself.

-your 2ed period stutent

Comment: @ihateme6, thanks for the info. Let's look into it further this week. We'll test it with .html to see if it works.